# Format unlocked cells with VBA in a protected sheet but not locked cells

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a worksheet with VBA to colour cells on double click in a portion of the sheet. These cells are unlocked but the cells around them are locked. I want to be able to prevent format of surrounding cells being changed but do want the VBA to change colour of unlocked cells. I would be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You want only macro changes to take effect? Protect the user interface:

`Sheet1.Protect Password:="Password", UserInterfaceOnly:=True`

Comment: This is amazing. I have never used VBA to control sheet protect except for unprotecting, making changes, and reprotecting. This negates that need entirely. `UserInterfaceOnly = True to protect the user interface, but not macros. If this argument is omitted, protection applies both to macros and to the user interface.` An addendum: Either protect the VBA project or use this line to protect the sheet initially and then delete it. Otherwise, anyone peeking at the code can get the password. (Yes, I know sheet protection is inherently weak but let's not make it *too* easy.)